# Pokemon Enemy Random Generator

Tags: java

Apparently I'm trying to make a pokemon simulator using Java and have a question for this(so far I only managed to make the basic JFrame with a moving oval(will be modified later as the moving character) in a window). How do I code random encounter with enemies like one in a pokemon game(using Java)? Thanks a lot. I'm new and will be pleased if anyone is willing to guide me on this game making.

Comment: You can use e.g. [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) for a source of randomness. You presumably want some kind of set for each type of terrain, where each encounter has a weighting that represents its likelihood. This question is too broad currently.

Comment: first: it's not java. It's game design. If you need java random number generator, there is a lot of tutorials on the interntet

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! This forum helps you with a programmer questions, related to configuration or the code. But not with the general questions as this one is.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies! I was actually trying to post my codes here but didnt know how to do so(I used ctrl k on the codes but still cant). Any suggestions on that? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read a little on how games work. you could generate random world coordinates where you have a probability of encountering a pokemon in that given range over time :D. then you could build up on this by defining biome coordinates that would generate only specific types of pokemon with a given probability.